# r data manipulation creating multiple records

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have two data frames as the following.

```
v1  v2
a   0.3
b   0.5
c   0.6
d   0.5
```

and

```
v3
aa
ab
ac
ad
```

I want the data frames to be as follows.

```
v1  v2  v3
a   0.3 aa
a   0.3 ab
a   0.3 ac
a   0.3 ad
b   0.5 aa
b   0.5 ab
b   0.5 ac
b   0.5 ad
c   0.6 aa
c   0.6 ab
c   0.6 ac
c   0.6 ad
d   0.5 aa
d   0.5 ab
d   0.5 ac
d   0.5 ad
```

Can someone tell me how to do this? The reason for creating this data frame is to make multiple scenario's for a logistic regression output.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share what you have tried yourself? We shouldn't be writing your code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge will work!!

```
merge(df2, df1)[,c("v1", "v2", "v3")]

# v1  v2 v3
# 1   a 0.3 aa
# 2   a 0.3 ab
# 3   a 0.3 ac
# 4   a 0.3 ad
# 5   b 0.5 aa
# 6   b 0.5 ab
# 7   b 0.5 ac
# 8   b 0.5 ad
# 9   c 0.6 aa
# 10  c 0.6 ab
# 11  c 0.6 ac
# 12  c 0.6 ad
# 13  d 0.5 aa
# 14  d 0.5 ab
# 15  d 0.5 ac
# 16  d 0.5 ad
```

Comment: Nice solution. `merge(df1,df2)` gives the same result, although unsorted.

Comment: Yes @PierreLafortune, because of sorting I specified the column names !!

Answer (score 3):

We can replicate **each** row of `df` 4 times, and consequently `cbind` it with `df2$v3` x 4.

```
cbind(df[rep(1:nrow(df), each = 4), ], v3 = rep(df2$v3, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `CJ` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(1:nrow(df1), 1:nrow(df2))[,c(df1[V1,],list(v3=df2[V2,]))]
#    v1  v2 v3
# 1:  a 0.3 aa
# 2:  a 0.3 ab
# 3:  a 0.3 ac
# 4:  a 0.3 ad
# 5:  b 0.5 aa
# 6:  b 0.5 ab
# 7:  b 0.5 ac
# 8:  b 0.5 ad
# 9:  c 0.6 aa
#10:  c 0.6 ab
#11:  c 0.6 ac
#12:  c 0.6 ad
#13:  d 0.5 aa
#14:  d 0.5 ab
#15:  d 0.5 ac
#16:  d 0.5 ad
```

NOTE: It is dynamic as it changes with the number of rows in each dataset.